# Autofac Registration based on appsettings config file

Tags: c#, configuration, autofac, appsettings

Is there a way to register components with Autofac if certain configuration information exists in the appsettings?

For example:

If the section HistorianSdk exists in the config file, register this layer.

[Appsettings example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVARc.png)

```
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        **// Todo: do this based on config file**
        RegisterHistorianSdkLayer(builder);
    }

        private void RegisterHistorianSdkLayer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(TagsReader).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
            .Where(x => x.Namespace != null && x.Namespace.Contains("Repositories"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.Register(c =>
        {
            var config = c.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
            var sdkConfigurations =
                config.GetSection("Plugins:HistorianSdk").Get<IEnumerable<HistorianSdkConfig>>();

            return sdkConfigurations;
        }).SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<DataPointMapper>()
            .AsSelf()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<Domain.HistorianSdk.Config.ConnectionFactory>()
            .AsSelf()
            .InstancePerDependency();
    }
```

If Yes, what is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass properties to an autofac module while registering it in `startup.cs`.

**When using the following `appsettings.json` file:**

```
{
  "UseSdk": true
}
```

**You can pass the properties like this during registration:**

```
builder.RegisterModule(new Bootstrap
{
   UseHistorianSdk = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("UseSdk");
});
```